# How to create 2d of pairwise comparisons in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to create 2d matrix of pairwise comparisons in JavaScript using 2 for loops

I want to create array like this

```
 0   1   1   1   1  -1
-1   0  -1  -1   1  -1
-1   1   0  -1   1  -1
-1   1   1   0   1  -1
-1  -1  -1  -1   0  -1
 1   1   1   1   1   0
```

How to do it in JavaScript I have this function. Object array has smth like this 6 1 4 3 2 5

```
const createMatrix = () =>{
    const array = []
    for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < object.length; j++) {
        if(object[i].id > object[j].id){
          return "1"
        }else if(object[i].id < object[j].id){
          return "-1"
        }else{
          return "0"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that `return` immediately breaks out of your loops?

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
const createMatrix = () =>{
const array = new Array(object.length)
for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
  const tempArr = []
  for (let j = 0; j < object.length; j++) {
    if(object[i].id > object[j].id){
      tempArr.push(1)
    }else if(object[i].id < object[j].id){
      tempArr.push(-1)
    }else{
      tempArr.push(0)
    }
  }
  array.push(tempArr)
}
console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: It's silly have a function that doesn't accept any input parameters and relies on variables from the scope it's in instead. `object` should have been passed to the function as a parameter.